# Problems with action in form

Tags: forms, redirect, action

I use the next form:

form action="/regForm" method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'

I need redirect to

localhost:8080/SiteDesigner/regForm

but get redirect to

localhost:8080/regForm

Where is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by starting the action with `/`, you are making the form submit relative to the domain. If you must really have it submit to `/SiteDesigner/regForm` then have it like so !

```
form action="/SiteDesigner/regForm" method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'
```